# Excel Mac 2016 vba fill.Userpicture from range

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2016

I have  a spreadsheet with multiple shapes that I'd like to fill using a range of file paths to different images. It worked on Excel 2011 for Mac, but not on 2016 - throwing a Run-time error '70': permission denied. After doing some digging, I found the GrantAccessToMultipleFiles method, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything and I still get the permission denied error. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Example code:

```
Sub changePic()
  fileList = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20"))
  success = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(fileList)

  MsgBox(success & " - " & fileList(1))
  'success = True, fileList(1) = "Users:xdesai:Desktop:Picture1.png"

  For i = 1 to 20
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Player " & i).Fill
      .Visible = True
      .UserPicture picturefile:=Range("A"&i).Value 'This is where I hit the permission denied error
    End With
  Next i
End Sub
```

I have no idea if I'm missing a step (there doesn't seem to be any actual issue with the images themselves - it all worked on 2011), or if it is something that just isn't working.

Comment: You should be using `/` and not `:` in the path in 2016

Comment: Well that was an incredibly simple solution to the problem. Thank you!